# Javascript/JSON pull key values based on highest key value value within property

Tags: javascript, html, json

The code below filters the JSON to find all "CDNAME" values based on the following key-value pair "AREAID":"area4" and displays it in the div with the blue border so that if area4 is changed to area3 it will display the respective max.

I want the code to then filter the list from the div with blue border and display "CDNAME" value with the highest "CDUID" value inside `<p id="demog" style="border: 2px solid green;"></p>`, in this case it will be:

**Division No. 19**

I am assuming the blue border array has to be checked against all CDUID values.

How to do that?

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {



  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObjjj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    var result = Array.from(new Set(myObjjj.features.filter(c => c.properties.AREAID === "area4").map(res => "<li>" + res.properties.CDNAME + "</li>"))).sort().join('');
    document.getElementById("demob").innerHTML = "<ul>" + result + "</ul>";
    
    

  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.npoint.io/d901ff317ae962d8c376", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Read data from External JSON file using JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Data extracted from External JSON file using JavaScript.</h3>
  <p id="demob" style="border: 2px solid blue;"></p>
  <h3>Divison with Highest CDUID VALUE From Div With Blue Border.</h3>
  <p id="demog" style="border: 2px solid green;"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Json from URL - https://api.npoint.io/d901ff317ae962d8c376

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4811","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 11","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4807","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 7","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4815","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 15","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4802","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 2","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4808","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 8","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4803","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 3","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4806","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 6","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4816","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 16","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4812","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 12","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4805","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 5","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4817","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 17","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4813","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 13","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4810","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 10","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4819","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 19","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4818","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 18","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4814","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 14","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4809","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 9","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the max value of from the array and when you are returning the element you can check if the item is having max value then return element with border. Have a look at below example.

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObjjj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    const filteredArray = myObjjj.features.filter(c => c.properties.AREAID === "area4")
    
    const maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, filteredArray.map(function({properties}) { return properties["CDUID"]; }))
    

    var result = Array.from(new Set(filteredArray.map(res => {
    if (res.properties['CDUID'] == maxValue) {
      return `<li style="border: 1px solid green">` + res.properties.CDNAME + "</li>";
    }
    return "<li>" + res.properties.CDNAME + "</li>";
    }))).sort().join('');
    document.getElementById("demob").innerHTML = "<ul>" + result + "</ul>";
    
    

  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.npoint.io/d901ff317ae962d8c376", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Read data from External JSON file using JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Data extracted from External JSON file using JavaScript.</h3>
  <p id="demob" style="border: 2px solid blue;"></p>
  <h3>Divison with Highest CDUID VALUE From Div With Blue Border.</h3>
  <p id="demog" style="border: 2px solid green;"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I noticed that the code takes max of the whole JSON, not the array. For exxample if I switch AREAID === "area4", to  AREAID === "area3" there will be no result.

Comment: I have updated code to match your scenario